# find elements summing to s in an array

Tags: algorithm

given an array of elements (all elements are unique ) , given a sum 
s   find all the subsets having sum s. 
for ex  array `{5,9,1,3,4,2,6,7,11,10}` 
sum is 10 
possible subsets are `{10}, {6,4}, {7,3}, {5,3,2}, {6,3,1}` etc.
there can be many more. 
also find the total number of these subsets.
please help me to solve this problem..

Comment: As this _seems_ homework, I suggest posting what you tried o far, so we can help you through that

Comment: This is NP complete. Just do an exaustive search then.

Comment: @missingno: the search is not necessarily exhaustive: you don't need to use elements of the input array whose value is bigger than the target sum

Comment: @MarcoS: Of course you can prune the search tree in many cases or try to exploit some simetry here and there (to imporve runtime in practice), but no such strategy will make the assymptotic behaviour better than exaustive search in this case.

Answer (score 2):

It is a famous backtracking problem which can be solved by recursion. Basically its a brute force approach in which every possible combination is tried but 3 boundary conditions given at least prune the search.
Here is algorithm:
s variable for the sum of elements selected till now.
r variable for the overall sum of the remaining array.
M is the sum required.
k is index starting with 0
w is array of given integers

```
Sum(k,s,r)
{
    x[k]:=1;  //select the current element
    if(s<=M & r>=M-s & w[k]<=M-s)
    then
    {
        if(s+w[k]==M)
        then output all i [1..k] that x[i]=1
        else
        sum(k+1,s+w[k],r-w[k])
    }
    x[k]:=0  //don't select the current element
    if(s<=M) & (r>=M-s) & (w[k]<=M-s)
    then
    {
        if (M==s)
        then output all i [1..k] that x[i]=1
        else
        sum(k+1,s,r-w[k])
    }
}
```

I am using an array "x" to mark the candidate numbers selected for solution. At each step 3 boundary conditions are checked:

```
1. Sum of selected elements in "x" from "w" shouldn't exceed M. s<M.    
2. Remaining numbers in array should be able to complete M. r>=M-s.
3. Single remaining value in w shouldn't overflow M. w[k]<=M-s.
```

If any of the condition is failed, that branch is terminated.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some python code doing what you want. It makes extensive use of itertools so to understand it you might want to have a look at the [itertools docs](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html).

```
>>> import itertools
>>> vals = (5,9,1,3,4,2,6,7,11,10)
>>> combos = itertools.chain(*((x for x in itertools.combinations(vals, i) if sum(x) == 10) for i in xrange(len(vals)+1)))
>>> for c in combos: print c
...
(10,)
(9, 1)
(3, 7)
(4, 6)
(5, 1, 4)
(5, 3, 2)
(1, 3, 6)
(1, 2, 7)
(1, 3, 4, 2)
```

What it does is basically this:

- For all possible subset sizes - `for i in xrange(len(vals)+1)`, do:
- Iterate over all subsets with this size - `for x in itertools.combinations(vals, i)`
- Test if the sum of the subset's values is 10 - `if sum(x) == 10`
- In this case yield the subset

For each subset size another generator is yielded, so I'm using `itertools.chain` to chain them together so there's a single generator yielding all solutions.

Since you have only a generator and not a list, you need to count the elements while iterating over it - or you could use `list(combos)` to put all values from the generator into a list (this consumes the generator, so don't try iterating over it before/after that).

Comment: How can I Find no.of elements inside combos generated by the generator?? @ThiefMaster

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't say if it's homework or not, I give only some hints:

- let `nums` be the array of numbers that you can use (in your example `nums = {5,9,1,3,4,2,6,7,11,10}`)
- let `targetSum` be the sum value you're given (in your example `targetSum = 10`)
- sort `nums`: you don't want to search for solutions using elements of `nums` that are bigger of your `targetSum`
- let `S_s` be a set of integers taken from `nums` whose sum is equal to `s`
- let `R_s` be the set of all `S_s`
- you want to find `R_s` (in your example `R_10`)
- now, assume that you have a function `find(i, s)` which returns `R_s` using the the sub-array of `nums` starting from position `i`

  - if `nums[i] > s` you can stop (remember that you have previously sorted `nums`)
  - if `nums[i] == s` you have found `R_s = { { nums[i] } }`, so return it
  - for every `j in [1 .. nums.length - 1]` you want to compute `R_s' = find(i + j, targetSum - nums[i])`, then add `nums[i]` to every set in `R_s'`, and add them to your result `R_s`
- solve your problem by implementing `find`, and calling `find(0, 10)`

I hope this helps