# Find all subset sum using dynamic programming

Tags: python, algorithm

I want to use dynamic programming to find all subset of an array that sums to a target,like:

arr = [1,3,2,4]

target = 6

output:

[1,3,2],[2,4]

How can i modify the code to get solution? thanks

```
def CheckSubsetSum(S, M):
    n = len(S)
    subset = np.array([[True]*(M+1)]*(n+1))
    for i in range(0,n):
        subset[i,0] = True

    for j in range(1,M+1):
        subset[0,j] =False 

    for i in range(1,n+1):
        for j in range(1,M+1):
            if j<S[i-1]:
                subset[i,j] = subset[i-1,j]
            else:
                subset[i,j] = subset[i-1,j] or subset[i-1,j-S[i-1]]
    print(subset)
CheckSubsetSum([1,3,2,4],6)
```

Comment: It's like a  _Knapsack problem_. Also you should to add tags, such as [tag:algorithm]

Comment: From the name of function, seems like the function checks if the array has the subset which equals given sum!

Comment: This is called a Knapsack problem, and there are many questions & answers around for this, e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5702537/565489)